# Defining and invoking a constructor in Fortran

Tags: oop, types, interface, fortran

I can't figure out how I define a simple constructor for a class. What I want to do is allocate an array in `mytype` and later populate it in the main program.

What I have is this:

```
module types
    implicit none

    type mytype
        real, allocatable :: someArray(:)
    end type mytype

    interface
        module procedure :: init
    end interface

contains
    subroutine init(this)
        class(mytype), intent(inout) :: this
        allocate( this%someArray(5) )
    end subroutine init
end module types

program test
  use types
  implicit none

  type(mytype) :: array

  call array%init
  do i=1, 5
    array%someArray(i) = real(i)
    print *, array%someArray(i)
  end do
end program test
```

When I compile I get the error

> Error: MODULE PROCEDURE at (1) must be in a generic module interface

What does that mean? How can I define a *generic module interface*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language's model for a user provided constructor is a generic function with the same identifier as the type, that simply returns an object of the type.   Beyond the ability to have a generic with the same name as a type, this is nothing special.

```
module types
  implicit none

  type mytype
    real, allocatable :: someArray(:)
  end type mytype

  interface mytype
    module procedure :: init
  end interface
  ! init would typically be private.
contains
  function init()
    type(mytype) :: this
    allocate( this%someArray(5) )
    ! Non-pointer function result must be defined.
    this%someArray = 0
  end function init
end module types

program test
  use types
  implicit none

  type(mytype) :: x

  x = mytype()

  do i=1, 5
    x%someArray(i) = real(i)
    print *, x%someArray(i)
  end do
end program test
```

(The example is somewhat pointless given other aspects of the language, such as parameterized types, array constructors, automatic allocation or even the out-of-the-box capability of the built-in structure constructors.)

The error message from the compiler perhaps means to reference a generic interface, as a procedure statement is only permitted in an interface block for a generic.

Specific type bound procedure references - things with the syntax `object % binding` - are generally used when you have a parent type that has a method with a particular signature (set of dummy arguments, bar the passed argument), and you want to *override* that method in extensions - i.e. invoke a different procedure that has the same signature.  Constructors don't fit this - typically the information that needs to be passed to a constructor (i.e. the signature of the call) is type specific.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! I'm clearly having no clue how to work with Fortran properly. Your hints opened up a total new world for me and I will try to use some of this for my implementations.

Comment: See "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf et al. You will find a thorough explanation of OOP in Fortran in this book along with examples.